# Call graph generator for OCaml or Reason

Tags: ocaml, analysis, call-graph, control-flow-graph, reason

I want to analyze a OCaml/Reason code repository and understand calls between various functions. Is there a tool that provides such functionality?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I actually never used it but only thing I can remember for OCaml is [pfff](https://github.com/returntocorp/pfff). Readme says that it supports codemaps and codegraphs.

Comment: There's example-screenshots for both of `pfff`'s visualisation tools: [`codemap`](https://github.com/facebook/pfff/wiki/Examples), [`codegraph`](https://github.com/facebook/pfff/wiki/CodeGraph#view-the-design-structure-matrix)

Answer (score 2):

One of the option is to take advantage of the existing OCaml editors or IDE since you can re-use their parsers to obtain the parsed tree or AST tree. I'm aware of two relatively good IDE for OCaml, which are:

- [OcaIDE](http://www.algo-prog.info/ocaide/) (written in Java)
- [Merlin](https://github.com/the-lambda-church/merlin) (written in OCaml)

Answer (score 1):

If your code compiles with OCaml 3.12, you can probably use Oug (http://home.gna.org/oug/)